# php doesn't execute after submit button is triggered

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to get data from a database and create a form with it.

```
        <?php
        $db = new mysqli("", "", "", "");       //Verbindungsaufbau zur DB 
        if ($db->connect_error) {                                                   //Fehlermeldung bei Verbindungsfehler
            die("Datenbankverbindung fehlgeschlagen.<br/>" . $db->connect_error);  
        }

        $news = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE author = "  . $author . " ORDER BY erstelltam ASC";               //SQL Abfragen

        if($stmt = $db->prepare($news)) {                                                       
            $stmt->execute();
            $anzeige = $stmt->get_result();
            $stmt->close();
        }
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($anzeige) ) {
            echo "<form method='POST' action=''  class='form-horizontal'>";

            echo "<img src='uploads/" . $row['bild'] . "' alt='" . $row['bild']  . "' width='304' height='236'>";

            echo "<h3>" . $row['name'] .  "</h3>";

            echo "<input type='submit' class='btn btn-default bearb' value='bearbeiten' name='bearbeiten'>";

            echo '</form>';
        }
        $db->close();

    ?>
```

This is working great. But when i try to submit the form with the submit button, nothing happens. 
I'm trying to get a simple echo but it doesn't get triggered.

```
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['bearbeiten'])) {
                echo "test";
            }
        ?>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: your `action = ''` in your forms so nothing happen.remove action part and add the last code on the same page and check (after removal of `action=''` from  all forms  will lead them to submit  onto  the current page only)

Comment: how many forms does it render?

Comment: Setting a blank `action` attribute (or not defining it at all) will cause the form to submit to the **same page** as the form appears on. This isn't valid HTML5 however, and opens your page up to attacks. Try setting `action="#"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help.

On the submit buttons was also an onclick event. In the function from the event i had a 'return false'... That was the mistake.